# ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets extension is not working

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REVRx.png)
my estension not working does anyone know?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved that;

**1)Launch Quick Open:**
Linux: `Ctrl+P`
macOS: `⌘P`
Windows: `Ctrl+P`

**2)Paste the following command and press Enter:**

`ext install dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets`